# How to write a recursive CTE query to find the parent record?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am having trouble writing a query which would return the parental id.
I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE csx
(
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, 
    cd VARCHAR(11), 
    category VARCHAR(20),
    lvl INT, 
    parent_id INT
)

INSERT INTO csx 
VALUES
(1,"ab-00-00-00",'ab',1,null),
(2,"ac-00-00-00",'ac',1,null),
(3,"ac-01-00-00",'ac',2,2),
(4,"ac-01-00-01",'ac',3,3),
(5,"ac-01-00-02",'ac',3,3),
(6,"ac-03-00-00",'ac',2,2),
(7,"ac-03-00-01",'ac',3,6),
(8,"ac-03-00-02",'ac'3,6),
(9,"ac-02-00-00",'ac'2,2),
(10,"ac-02-00-01",'ac',3,9)
```

I want to check whether *parent_id* (referencing the *id* of the entry) is correct.

I am new to recursive CTEs (I think those have to be used). Could you please shed some light on the correct way to implement the CTE which would return parental ids?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I basically have to come up with a query verifying that parent_id. You see, the 2nd entry is parental for the 3rd and the 9th, the 3rd for the 4th,5th, et cetera.

Comment: You write that you want to check whether `parent_id` is correct. How do you know whether it is correct? For instance, with the last row `(10,"ac-02-00-01",3,9)`, what is it that means that `parent_id` (9) is right or wrong?

Comment: Search for "sql adjacency list cte examples"

Comment: @markusk well, you see its correctness when you check the names 'ac-02-00-00' and 'ac-02-00-01', the last being one level deeper and the first having id=9

Comment: You only need a self join to find whether a `ParentID` referst to a non-existent ID: `select t1.* FROM csx t1 left join csx t2 on t1.ParentID=t1.ID where t2.ID is null`. The names have no obvious relation to `ID` or `ParentID` - where did this `ab` or `ac` come from?

Comment: You can replace the `ParentID` and quite possibly even `cd` with a `hierarchyid` column. That's essentially a path along the hierarchy using the PK values. This makes finding children very easy, as all children will have a `hierarchyid` that starts with the parent's path. There are several functions to retrieve parent IDs, levels and construct actual paths based eg on names etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I somewhat expanded the table to show where these ab or ac come from

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I thought about getting the data from the column cd (splitting it into the letters and the subsequent digital parts), but I thought it would be too cumbersome

Comment: That's worse actually, because `cd` contains a mix of different values. Don't do that. What happens if you rename a category anyway? You can construct the `cd` value easily with a recursive CTE or if you use `hierarchyid`. You definitely can't use it to determine ID values

Comment: `it would be too cumbersome` not cumbersome - wrong. What happens if a category is renamed ? Why do you assume `cd` is wrong, when the table, especially if there's a self-referencing Foreign Key, guarantees that `ParentID` is correct?

Comment: BTW the best way to avoid bad ParentIDs is to add an FK that *ensures* there can never be an invalid ParentID

Comment: The `cd` values don't even contain IDs. These seem to be row numbers inside the same level. These can't be used to validate anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you don't quite get it, the data are valid, and the table is devised exactly this way. So, I need some CTEs to get the parental id.
Perhaps, I may use some wildcards, may I?

Comment: It's your job to ensure people get it. Right now it's unclear what you want. It *is* clear that `cd` can't be used to validate anything though. There's no way to go from a `01` at the fourth part to ParentID 9. That `01` is a row number inside the parent's children. You can't calculate that row number without already knowing all the other parents and children. You can *replicate* `cd` by reconstructing the tree (with a CTE), calculating the row number (using ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PARENT_ID ORDER BY ID)` and comparing the new path to `cd`. **BUT** where did those `00` come from?

Comment: Let me clarify it. Consider, for instance, row 9 having entry

Comment: Why does ID 10 have `"ac-02-00-01"` instead of `"ac-02-01-00"` ? It's a third-level item, not a first level one. Also why is ID 6 an `ac-03` but ID 9 an `ac-02`? `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(... ORDER BY ID)` will generate `ac-03` for 6. Changing the order will break the other `cd`s.

Comment: If the `cd` logic is inconsistent there's no way to ensure the `Parent_ID` match it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to verify values after the fact, ensure there can never be invalid `ParentID`s with a foreign key :

```
CREATE TABLE csx
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    cd VARCHAR(11), 
    category VARCHAR(20),
    lvl INT, 
    parent_id INT references csx(id)
)
```

If you wanted to ensure there are no invalid ParentIDs in an existing table, a simple LEFT JOIN would be enough to find all problems:

```
SELECT t1.*
from csx t1 left join csx t2 on t1.ParentID=t2.ID
where t2.ID is null
```

This will return all rows with a non-existent ParentID. The FOREIGN KEY on the other hand ensures there won't be any invalid values in the first place.

To calculate levels and paths you can use a recursive CTE. A CTE is more-or-less a subquery that can be referenced by name and used in multiple places. A recursive CTE is a CTE that refers to itsel.

To get all root items and their children, the following CTE first selects all roots, then joins the actual table with itself to retrieve the children :

```
with cte as (
    select csx.* ,
        1 as Level,
        cast(ID as varchar(200)) as Path
    from csx
    where parent_id is null
    union all
    select csx.* ,
        cte.Level+1 as Level,
        cast(CONCAT_WS('/',cte.Path, csx.ID) as varchar(200)) As Path
    from csx inner join cte on cte.ID=csx.parent_id 
)
select * from cte
order by path
```

| id | cd | category | lvl | parent_id | Level | Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ab-00-00-00 | ab | 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | ac-00-00-00 | ac | 1 | NULL | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | ac-01-00-00 | ac | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2/3 |
| 4 | ac-01-00-01 | ac | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2/3/4 |
| 5 | ac-01-00-02 | ac | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2/3/5 |
| 6 | ac-03-00-00 | ac | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2/6 |
| 7 | ac-03-00-01 | ac | 3 | 6 | 3 | 2/6/7 |
| 8 | ac-03-00-02 | ac | 3 | 6 | 3 | 2/6/8 |
| 9 | ac-02-00-00 | ac | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2/9 |
| 10 | ac-02-00-01 | ac | 3 | 9 | 3 | 2/9/10 |

The first query selects the roots and sets the root values for the Level (1) and Path (ID). The next query joins the table with the CTE to match roots and children.

The question's `cd` column isn't a path though. It looks like a row number inside each parent's direct children. Calculating row numbers is the job of the ROW_NUMBER function. Since we're counting inside a parent's children, we can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Parent_ID ORDER BY ID)`.

```
with cte as (
    select csx.* ,
        1 as Level,
        cast(category as varchar(200)) as Path
    from csx
    where parent_id is null
    union all
    select csx.* ,
        cte.Level+1 as Level,
        cast(CONCAT_WS('-',cte.Path, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY csx.Parent_ID ORDER BY csx.ID)) as varchar(200)) As Path
    from csx inner join cte on cte.ID=csx.parent_id 
)
select * from cte
order by path;
```

This produces

| id | cd | category | lvl | parent_id | Level | Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ab-00-00-00 | ab | 1 | NULL | 1 | ab |
| 2 | ac-00-00-00 | ac | 1 | NULL | 1 | ac |
| 3 | ac-01-00-00 | ac | 2 | 2 | 2 | ac-1 |
| 4 | ac-01-00-01 | ac | 3 | 3 | 3 | ac-1-1 |
| 5 | ac-01-00-02 | ac | 3 | 3 | 3 | ac-1-2 |
| 6 | ac-03-00-00 | ac | 2 | 2 | 2 | ac-2 |
| 7 | ac-03-00-01 | ac | 3 | 6 | 3 | ac-2-1 |
| 8 | ac-03-00-02 | ac | 3 | 6 | 3 | ac-2-2 |
| 9 | ac-02-00-00 | ac | 2 | 2 | 2 | ac-3 |
| 10 | ac-02-00-01 | ac | 3 | 9 | 3 | ac-3-1 |

Unfortunately, the values don't match. With `ORDER BY ID`, the row with ID 6 will have a path `ac-2` instead of `ac-3`. Changing the order will break all other rows. There's no other indicator that could be used to determine the row number of the children, at least not in this table.

This means that either rows 6-10 are all wrong, or that`cd` can't be used to determine if `Parent_ID` is wrong. It doesn't contain identifiers but calculated values. The only way to say if the data match these, is to try and reproduce them. Unfortunately, there's not enough information in the table to do so